# AJAX call not succeeding in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get the number of images from a directory on my server. I'm using PHP to figure out the number of images, and AJAX (in my chrome extension) to get the number of images from my external PHP file.

It is going through the **success: function{}** but is not running the the **if(data){}**. It also occasionally alerts the error, saying The following error occurred: error. How do I fix this?

**main.js**

```
...


(function ($) {
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
           $.ajax({
               url: 'http://website.com/numberOfImages.php',     // <== POINTS TO THE VALID URL OF THE PHP FILE THAT OUTPUTS THE NUMBER OF IMAGES...
               dataType: "HTML",
               cache: false,
               type: "POST",

               //HANDLE THE SUCCESS CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
               success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                   if(data){
                       alert(data);
                   }
               },

               //HANDLE THE FAILURE CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
               error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert('The following error occurred: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
               },

               //HANDLE THE EVENT-COMPLETE CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
               complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
               }
           });
       });
   })(jQuery);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "description": "Add description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "main.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "some title"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**numberOfImages.php**

```
<?php

    $dir        = "/home/some/directory";
    $fi         = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $fileCount  = iterator_count($fi);

    die($fileCount);

?>
```

Comment: From [die/exit reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) __If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed__ So your script isnt printing anything, unless you are not showing some other code that does. This means `data` is going to be an empty string, which is falsey. Don't use die as a print command, its meant for status messages. Just `echo` out the number and end the script

Comment: So I should just echo out the integer and the AJAX will pick it up?

Comment: It worked, thanks @PatrickEvans! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PatrickEvans comment answered my question. Thanks.

My updated code:

```
<?php

    $dir        = "/home/some/directory";
    $fi         = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $fileCount  = iterator_count($fi);

    echo $fileCount;

?>
```